# c# list and enumerator with properties

Tags: c#, list, properties, enumeration

I have the following problem:
I have a list and add string items to this list. 
Then I create an Enumerator out of the list. When I loop through the list with the `MoveNext()` command it works when I access the enumerator directly. When I use the Enumerator properties to access the enumerator it doesn't work. The `MoveNext()` command doesn't increment the index.

Here is the code I used. Thanks a lot for your help.

```
public class DummyKlasse
{
    public List<string>.Enumerator enumerator;
    public List<string> list;

    public DummyKlasse()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
        list = new List<string>();
        enumerator = new List<string>.Enumerator();
    }

    public List<string>.Enumerator Enumerator
    {
        get { return enumerator; }
        set { enumerator = value;}
    }

    public List<string> List
    {
        get { return list; }
        set { list = new List<string>(value); }
    }        

    public void dummyfunction()
    {
        List.Add("test1");
        List.Add("test2");

        enumerator = List.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DummyKlasse dummyklasse = new DummyKlasse();
        dummyklasse.dummyfunction();

        //Does not work with properties
        /*
        while (dummyklasse.Enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dummyklasse.Enumerator.Current);
        }
        */
        //Works WITHOUT properties
        while (dummyklasse.enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dummyklasse.enumerator.Current);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is exactly your goal? Most of time, a simple `foreach` construct will allow you to iterate your data.

Comment: Answer using inheritance added

Answer (score 4):

[`List<T>.Enumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x854yt9s.aspx) is a struct, so in your while loop, each time you access the `Enumerator` property, you are calling the getter, which will return you a new copy of the enumerator each time. This enumerator will point to the item before th beginning of the list, and each call to `MoveNext` and `Current` will be done on a different copy of that enumerator.

As a result on a non-empty list, `MoveNext` will always return true, and `Enumerator.Current` is always null.

If you access the field directly, you are avoiding this copy and the same enumerator being accessed by the calls to `MoveNext` and `Current`.

If you change your code to:

```
using (var enumerator = dummyklasse.Enumerator)
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
    }
}
```

it will work as expected. Note this is similar to what the `foreach` statement does.

Comment: How does this address the fact that directly accessing the field in the OP's example works but the property does not?

Comment: @mao47 - If you access the field directly, you're not copying it.

Comment: For some reason I was still thinking of it as a variable even though I *knew* that it was a value. Structs can be tricky.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know that it will make a copy of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to capture an enumerator in your `DummyKlasse`?  Better just to capture the List itself (which you are doing), and let consumers worry about their own enumerators.  This is best done with the use of a `foreach` loop.

```
public class DummyKlasse
{
    public List<string> List { get; set; }

    public DummyKlasse() 
    {
        List = new List<string>();
    }

    public void Setup()
    {
        List.Add("one");
        List.Add("two");
    }
}

...

var dummy = new DummyKlasse();
dummy.Setup();

// the client does his own enumerating, not dummy.
foreach (var str in dummy.List)   
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```